# When does HTML5 video fetch and decode its video?

Tags: html5-video

I load 5 `<video autoplay>` elements on my page. On some older computers, this can take a lot of CPU.

At what point does a video element fetch its source video, and decode it?  Is it only when the video begins to play?

I'm not seeing any data in the "Network" tab in Chrome dev tools, so I'm not sure how to tell when the data is being fetched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `autoplay` is specified, the video automatically begins to play back as soon as it can do so without stopping to finish loading the data and it has nothing to to with when data is fetched.

You should use `preload` attribute to specify and leave out unbiguity.

This enumerated attribute is intended to provide a hint to the browser about what the author thinks will lead to the best user
   experience. It may have one of the following values:
- none: indicates that the video should not be preloaded.
- metadata: indicates that only video metadata (e.g. length) is fetched.
- auto: indicates that the whole video file could be downloaded, even if the user is not  expected to use it. the empty string: synonym of the auto value.

***Note:*** If not set, its default value is browser-defined (i.e. each browser may have its default value). The spec advises it to be set to metadata.

***Note:*** Some versions of Chrome only acknowledge autostart, rather than autoplay